# v5 DataGrid Show column header-row divider on pinned columns

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to style pinned columns in MUI's DataGrid so that it shows the column header-row divider.

In [MUI's official demo for pinned columns [https://codesandbox.io/s/qix39o?file=/demo.tsx]](https://codesandbox.io/s/qix39o?file=/demo.tsx), it shows the pinned column header without that bottom outline like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnAV0.png), but I want it to resemble the header-row divider of other non-pinned columns [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY0hl.png) (Note the faint gray divider line near the bottom of the screenshot).

Any pointers to CSS classes and properties are appreciated!

EDIT: [Here's a side-by-side picture of what I mean for further clarification. enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz9ig.png)

EDIT: I got it working. Please see my answer below. Any improvements or feedback is also welcome.

Comment: In the https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/ api docs you can access the column headers css with .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader. I ended up setting up a theme provider and overwring the styles there as it makes it more efficient when your app grows. Just check the api as I'm sure you'll find the css class there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out below by overriding borderTop property for class .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller. Thank you for everyone's help!

```
export default function BasicColumnPinning() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 420, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPro
        sx={{
          ".MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller": {
            borderTop: "1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)"
          }
        }}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{ pinnedColumns: { left: ["name"], right: ["actions"] } }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed it, so the border for the Email section in the middle needs a height of 420 like so:

```
    export default function BasicColumnPinning() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 420, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPro
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{ pinnedColumns: { left: ["name"], right: ["actions"] 

} }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Before the height was 400. That takes care of the header-row divider.
Next for the "tables" and "action" section. The row below has a specific border-bottom property preventing the top border from showing. If you go to developer tools and inspect the padding around "Virginia Herr..." and find border-bottom and switch it to just "border". Hope this helps.